# When are context processors called?

Tags: python, flask, server

I am using context processors (`@app.context.processor`) to store the user's cash. I am doing this because the user's cash is always going to be displayed on the top of the page, so I don't want to pass it as an argument every single time.

I have this:

```
@app.context_processor
def global_variables():
    def getUserCash():
        return Decimal(db.execute("SELECT cash FROM users WHERE id = :id", id=session["user_id"])[0].get("cash", None))
    return dict(getUserCash=getUserCash)
```

My question is: are context processors functions only updated when the user opens the website for the first time? Or does it get updated every time there's a request in the server (`GET` and/or `POST`)?

I am asking this because, for efficiency and optimization, I only want Flask to get the user's cash only once (when the user logs in), and only updates it when the user buys or sells something (not when changing pages).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/templating/#context-processors):

> Context processors run before the template is rendered and have the ability to 
>   inject new values into the template context

If you're not rendering a template I wouldn't expect to have the context processor run.

If you don't want to hit your database on every rendered template, you could use `flask.session` to store a user's cash, then update the session value appropriately.

Comment: Mmm, thanks. Do you by any chance know if there is a way to have multiple sessions at the same time? Because I already have one for the user's ID.

Comment: A session is a cookie stored on the client's computer. On the user's machine. Sessions are already supposed to be multiple... https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sessions.htm Record some username or generate a random hash to differentiate them and store in the database (with the user key) if you must.

Answer (score 1):

(Note: the answer below assumed the need for persistency of changes)

Context processors will run before resolving your template and bind the value of `getUserCash` to that returned by your function and therefore that value will persist until the template is reloaded.

So context processors are not what you are looking for.

You can however define two flask.session variables `session['cash_changed'] = True` and `session['cash'] = 0` to cache the user cash value to be used with a getter and a setter like this:

```
def getUserCash():
        if session.get('cash_changed',True):        
            session['cash'] = # Getter query here to get cash for the specific user
            session['cash_changed'] = False
        return session.get('cash',0)

def setUserCash(value):
        session['cash_changed'] = True
        session['cash'] = value
        # setter query to write the new cash value to the database for the user
```

Comment: As long as the `session['cash']` is updated when needed, I would stick with the context_processor and just grab it from the session

Comment: I think the context processor just binds it when it loads the page.... However please try and let me know

Comment: context processor passes the value into the template context, we're just pulling it out of the session instead of the database

Comment: @afro I think I'm just over complicating stuff but thanks you guys. I think my solution is just to set `session["user_cash"] = #getUser'sCashFromDatabase...` only ONCE when the user logs in and then whenever the user buys or sells something, I just update it with: `session["user_cash"] = #newValue`. I feel dumb now

Comment: that's pretty much the idea

Comment: @afro Just one last question: is it dangerous to call `session["user_cash"]` in front end using Javascript? Say: `alert({{ session["user_cash") }});`

Comment: @kibe I will answer to you... Javascript has no access to that variable.

Comment: @kibe Also your original point and the way I understood your question and answered it, was supposed to implement persistency. Sessions are volatile, if the cookie expires or is lost. That way changes are lost. With persistency every single change that had actually made a difference would have been saved to the database for that user. While for your case it proved unnecessary, it is a whole new feature, which I assumed you needed :)